# Oracle SQL - Why does select to_char(to_date('31-DEC-18'),'YYYY-IW') from dual; return 2018-01?

Tags: sql, oracle

When using Oracle SQL, why does the select statement

```
select to_char(to_date('31-DEC-18'), 'YYYY-IW') 
from dual;
```

return '2018-01'?

I understand that 'IW' uses the ISO standard, which is what I want to use, but as far as I can tell from my research, December 31, 2018 occurs during week 1 of 2019, according to the ISO standard. So I understand why the select statement returns '01' for the 'IW', but why does it return '2018' for the 'YYYY'? Shouldn't the statement return '2019-01'?

For the data I am using, it is preferable to use IW instead of WW.

Comment: Nothing in the doc says the result of date formatting  would be meaningful . Every part of the format works independently. Year? it's 2018. Iso week? it's 01. You want to combine then in a single string? no problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you may need is the ISO year format `IYYY`, according to [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TO_CHAR-datetime.html#GUID-0C3EEFD1-AE3D-452D-BF23-2FC95664E78F):

```
SQL> select to_char( date '2018-12-31', 'IYYY-IW')
  2  from dual;

TO_CHAR
-------
2019-01
```

As an aside, by writing `to_date('31-DEC-18')` you are relying on some assumptions, which may not always be true; a safer way to write dates is the ANSI format: `date '2019-12-31'`

Comment: Thank you, Aleksej! That's exactly what I'm looking for. I didn't realize there was an ISO year format. The ISO standard is a new concept for me.

Comment: @KatherineReed - the date elements in the format model are always independent of each other. 'YYYY' is for **calendar** year, which in your example is 2018 (obviously!). 'IW' is for ISO week; the date is in the first ISO weak of ISO year 2019 (even though the **calendar** year is still 2018). To get the ISO year - which is the only one that makes sense to show with the ISO week number - you need the format element 'IYYY'. It is your (the programmer's) responsibility to use compatible elements, like IYYY and IW, in the format model; Oracle is not smart enough to do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

ISO year 2019 started on Dec 31 2018.  All weeks start on a Monday and by the rule used, that is the first week of 2019.  Oracle is correctly doing the calculation.  There are handy [references](https://www.epochconverter.com/weeks/2019) on-line for ISO dates.

You may want to review the rules for ISO weeks and years, say in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date).

Comment: Thank you for the response. I understand that ISO year 2019 started on Dec 31, 2018, but the the select statement is not returning 2019 for the year. It is returning 2018 for the year, and I don't understand why.